# How can I set a "bounding" area for my drag-able object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm making a Drag and Drop JavaScript engine. I learned how to set a bounding box as the parent element. However, now I wish to set the bounding box to any parent of any parent, or as the entire page (bound-less).

Right now my Javascript Engine looks like:

```
// JavaScript Document

var dragObj;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);

function down(event) {
    if(~event.target.className.search(/drag/)) {
        dragObj = makeObj(event.target);
        dragObj.element.style.zIndex="100";
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    }
}

function freeMovement(event) {

    if (typeof(dragObj.element.mouseup) == "undefined")
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //Prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly

    dragObj.element.style.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientX - dragObj.posX, dragObj.boundX)) + "px";
    dragObj.element.style.top = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientY - dragObj.posY, dragObj.boundY)) + "px";
}

function drop() {
    dragObj.element.style.zIndex="1";

    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //alert("DEBUG_DROP");
}

function makeBoundlessObj(e) {
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    return obj;
}

function makeObj(e) {
    obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (e.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += e.offsetLeft;
            curtop += e.offsetTop;
            //alert(e.id + ":" + e.innerHTML);
            if(~e.className.search(/bound/)) {
                obj.boundX = curleft - obj.element.offsetLeft;
                obj.boundY = curtop - obj.element.offsetTop;
                return obj;
            }

        } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    }

    return obj;
}

function findPos(obj) { // Donated by `lwburk` on StackOverflow
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
}
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.drag {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.bound {
    position: relative;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor:move;
}

#center {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
}

#box {
    background-color: #FF3;
    height: 278px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And my HTML is pretty clean:

```
<div id="center">
    <h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>
    <div id="box" class="bound">
        <p class="drag square"> One </p>
        <p class="drag square"> Two </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've attempted to make the proper functions multiple times. I'll give one that I've made which doesn't work, and I'll list why:

1. If it doesn't have bounds, I set the default bounds as the parent element (because I don't know how to set bounds as the entire page)
2. If one of the parent elements **IS** a bound, then I am not setting the bound coordinates correctly (again, I don't know how)

Oh, and I set the bounds while I create the drag_object.

JavaScript creation function:

```
function makeObj(e) {
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (e.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += e.offsetLeft;
            curtop += e.offsetTop;
            //alert(e.id + ":" + e.innerHTML);
            if(~e.className.search(/bound/)) {
                obj.boundX = curleft - obj.element.offsetLeft;
                obj.boundY = curtop - obj.element.offsetTop;
                return obj;
            }

        } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

What is the correct math for setting the bounding box and why? Can I get rid of the `position: relative` in the `.bound` class? Can I make `.drag` class not `position: absolute`? I know all of these things will probably greatly affect how the bounding function is written. If I **had** to choose between having the `.drag` class or the `.bound` class not need a certain type of `position`, I would choose that the `.bound` class be set to any kind of positioning.

Thank you all for reading and helping! It means a lot to me; I'm a full time (boarding) high school student with very little free time =/

EDIT:

I should note that I'm on my tenth day of learning Javascript- or fifteenth-hour depending on how you look at it, and I would like to learn the language before I start using libraries like jQuery. This engine is an academic exercise I've made for myself for the sake of knowledge and learning the language =]

Comment: +1 - definitely a worthy goal to learn JavaScript yourself rather than relying on libraries. However, you can probably learn a lot from deconstructing the source of the jQuery UI draggable library (which I know specifically supports setting any element to be a bounding box). Most of the code in jQuery UI is pretty clear if you can read JS, so it may help you along the way: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: @Tim thanks. I was actually thinking about reading about how different libraries did it, but when I look at other people's code, I have no idea what's going on. I don't know enough JavaScript yet. However, the last time I looked at someone's version of "drag and drop" was before I wrote a line of my own code, so it's quite possible that link will come in handy. If only code was heavily commented! Also, those libraries may help me with how I structure the code. I want to implement the engine so that it's easy to use.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that you didn't have a minimum boundary. You'll need that in order to enforce the upper AND lower bound.

*What is the correct math for setting the bounding box and why?*

First thing is that `dragObj` needs to account for both boundaries (applies to `position: absolute`):

```
// parentNode is our bounding box
// the minimum boundary is based on the top left corner of our container
obj.minBoundX = e.parentNode.offsetLeft;
obj.minBoundY = e.parentNode.offsetTop;

// the maximum is the bottom right corner of the container
// or.. the top left (x,y) + the height and width (h,y) - the size of the square
obj.maxBoundX = obj.minBoundX + e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
obj.maxBoundY = obj.minBoundY + e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;
```

Enforcing the boundaries is a simple update to `freeMovement`:

```
dragObj.element.style.left = Math.max(dragObj.minBoundX, Math.min(event.clientX - dragObj.posX, dragObj.maxBoundX)) + "px";
dragObj.element.style.top = Math.max(dragObj.minBoundY, Math.min(event.clientY - dragObj.posY, dragObj.maxBoundY)) + "px";
```

*Can I get rid of the position: relative in the .bound class?* Yup.

*Can I make .drag class not position: absolute?* Yup. You'll just want to change your positions to be relative and your calculations to account for this. For example, your minimum bound will now be 0.

```
// parentNode is our bounding box
// the minimum boundary is based on the top left corner of our container
obj.minBoundX = 0;
obj.minBoundY = 0;
```

Here is the JSFiddle for the `position:absolute` version: http://jsfiddle.net/feWcQ/ (works with Firefox 4). I also added two tiny boxes that show your boundaries. Hopefully my answer helps you!

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! I'm going to look through everything to make sure I understand it.

Comment: So, I have a bunch of questions! It appears the bounding box is set to be the parent element by default. Before I was preforming a check to find the correct parent element to use as a bounding box. Can I still do that? -Even if there is **any** type of position set (and how)? Also, how do I account for setting the `.drag` and `.bound` class to any type of positioning? What's the math like?

Comment: Sure you can still do that! You probably want to check `object.style.position` and then perform your calculations. When it is `relative`, then minBoundX and minBoundY would be 0 (as I have above).

Comment: So @Kit, how do I get from here http://jsfiddle.net/yJVtH/ to allowing different types of positioning in the math? Can you add in comments to the jsfiddle I just posted showing me where I need to adjust for different types of positioning?

Comment: Here is an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/yJVtH/3/. I made a couple of changes so take a look. I also think your math won't change like I thought it would. The only thing you need to figure out is a better `findPos` function that can account for relative/absolute positioning of the bounding element. For that, I definitely would recommend looking at how jQuery or prototype.js does it because there are a lot of quirks.. especially across browsers.

Comment: Forgot one thing in my previous comment.. You probably want to keep your draggable objects with an absolute position. I think it'll be easier to manage.

Comment: @Kit, I will take a look at how jQuery does it, and I'll post a new question about findPos(). However, with regards to your last comment, I can't keep it absolute! I want the developer to choose which type it is =]

Answer (score 2):

So, before I take a stab, I'd strongly recommend the book by OReilly, "Definitive Guide to JavaScript". I learned a ton in there (and subsequently forgot it when I didnt have to use it every day).

So there's a lot of ways to skin this cat, but I the hardest part is to get the positions of the relevant things in a cross-browser way without using a library.  I don't actually recall the exact syntax (so I won't try) but basically what you'll need to do is find the bounding box's position and the dragged element's position using this formula: http://blog.firetree.net/2005/07/04/javascript-find-position/ and then account for element widths and so on to stay inside the boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation. I'll take a look into obtaining it. As for the algorithm the link gives, I have a very similar function (last one in the engine) already called findPos(). It's 12AM here now, so I'll read the entire webpage in-depth tomorrow. Thank you! =]